# Where to stand after night out with "crush"

Tags: relationships, making-friends

My problem is, cannot wrap my head around this.

Through the internet I got to know a woman also living in my town, actually just 10 min per foot away. We wrote a few days and met a few times. The first time it was just standing and talking for 2 hours and then me getting her back home at 2am. The next day she got me out of bed at 10pm to go visit her, and we spent part of the night together and I left at 3am. We laughed and talked and had fun and during this I made my first attempts on touching her, and she let me, which I deemed as a good sign but left it at that because I were to meet at a concert and go out afterwards in two days.

During all this time we wrote almost the whole day with each other. And yesterday evening/night was the concert. We were in a group of 5 people, had tons of fun and with time and alcohol, I started touching her more, she did the same thing, and after the concert at a friend's home, we started making out, for the whole time we were there, so not just for a couple of minutes.

But sadly (might have had too much beer) I really got a stomachache and left to the bathroom because I thought I needed to puke, but actually fell asleep for like 10-15 min or so until she came in because she was worried about me, and encouraged me to puke so I would feel better and really refused to leave as she had no problem with this sort of thing, bound my hair back (have long hair, was a metal concert) and was really caring. Sometimes I stood up when I thought I felt a bit better, and we kissed and made out again an hugged and stuff. I didn't puke but I really really did not get better after some time and because I only had to walk 3 minutes home I left and went to bed. At the door she hugged me for like 5 min straight until I said I need to go out to the air because I'm getting really sick again.

She wrote me if I came home safely but I didn't see that and wrote with her today morning again. It was totally normal writing, to the sorts of yesterday was fun and so on and on, but what my problem now is..... Where do we stand? When I meet her the next time, which will clearly be in max 1-2 days if not today again going for meal with a few guys, where do we stand? Is it at a place where we could (just for sorting into categories) make out again when we were alone, or is it back at this light touchy thing, because when we made out we were drunk/she not that drunk actually.

**PS:** We both would be interested in relationship, but it does not need to be, at least from my part as I just don't want something complicated again. But if it fits and thats okey.

**PPS:** And I really hope this belongs to IPS as I have no idea where else to ask.

**Edit:** My question is on what bias people typically stand after a drunk night out with making out when they are sober again.
But everything played out well. Thanks for the answers and comments.

Comment: Have you ever had a very stressful situation? I've once come across a case of really bad stomach reaction... to stress. It just _may_ have been a combination of effects. If so, better lay off the alcohol totally when getting together again. At least until whatever is happening (and it sounds GOOD) has settled down.

Comment: "Where do we stand?" That's a question you need to ask her, not us.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with asking her this question :)

Answer (score 4):

If she was not drunk then she is OK with making out sober.

Go with the flow.  Visit with light touching.  If the moment strikes then kiss and see what follows.

Comment: Yep.  Regroup, drink less, talk more, go for round 2.